# Calling ApolloClient GraphQl request inside componentDidMount method

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am using ApolloClient GraphQl query inside react class to fetch data from server:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {useCompanyLogo} from '../../queries/companyLogo';


class Logo extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {logo: ""};
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        const {error, loading, data} = useCompanyLogo(); 
        if(loading) return <div>spinner</div>
        if(error) return <div>error!</div>
        const imageSource = data.companyLogo[0].image.urls[0];
             
        this.setState({logo: imageSource});
      }
      
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="logo-area">
                <a href="/"><img src={"http://computer-313:5000" + this.state.logo} alt="Businex-Logo"  style={{width:"80px"}} /></a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Logo;
```

And the query is as below:

```
import {useQuery, gql} from "@apollo/client";
var COMPANY_LOGO = gql`
query CompanyLogo {
    companyLogo {
      image {
        urls(first: 1)
      }
    }
  }
`;
export const useCompanyLogo = () => {
  const {error, data, loading} = useQuery(COMPANY_LOGO);
  console.log(error, data, loading);
  return {
    error,
    data,
    loading
  }
}
```

Everything works good when I use function instead of class But when I run this code I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the React.js documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both) you **cannot** use Hooks inside of Class Components.

> You can’t use Hooks inside a class component, but you can definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is an implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.

You can try to use [high order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and be able to *pass* the hooks into your Class Component that way.